# How to fetch all the details that are inside the td tag one by one by using HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, screen-scraping, htmlunit

**so far I have successfully grab some of the details from the sub-categories but that too is not enough. I've to grab each and every details as:**

Product Name :Shoes
Product Details :Shoes
Date :12-06-2020
Price :Rs. 2,500

(Brand New)

**Here Product Name and Product Details gives same result but which is not the required result I want.I want something like this:**

Product Name :Shoes
Product Details :Brand New Shoes Highcopy ...
Seller :s unil t
Date :12-06-2020
Price :Rs. 2,500
Usage :Brand New

**The Image for this particular item is**

[image]

**for your convenience this is the site I'm scraping**

https://hamrobazaar.com/c6-apparels-and-accessories

**The Code is as**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
            "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);

    final String url = "https://hamrobazaar.com/c6-apparels-and-accessories"
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX);
    HtmlPage rootPage = webClient.getPage(new URL(url));
    
    List<HtmlTable> tableElements = rootPage
            .getByXPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[5]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table");
    try{
    for (int i = 0; i < tableElements.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0 || 
                i == 1) {
            continue;
        }
        HtmlTableRow row = tableElements.get(i).getRow(0);
        HtmlTableCell productCell = row.getCell(2);
        if(productCell.getElementsByTagName("a").get(0).asText().equals(null)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            String productName = productCell.getElementsByTagName("a").get(0).asText();
            System.out.println("Product Name :"+productName);
        }
        System.out.println("Product Details :" +  productCell.getElementsByTagName("font").get(0).asText() );
        System.out.println("Date :" + row.getCell(3).asText());
        System.out.println("Price :" + row.getCell(4).asText());

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception raised");
}
```

}
**Please, help me to sort out this. Tons of Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick check with the page by using the FF developer tools to check the dom tree.

Your code searches inside the font tag for the product details

```
System.out.println("Product Details :" +  productCell.getElementsByTagName("font").get(0).asText() );
```

but as far as i can see the text you are looking for is outside the font tag.

[image]

I think you have to use the sibling of the sibling of the font tag.